# How do I switch applications in windows7

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I wanted to use ctrl alt tab along with the arrow keys to switch applications in windows 7. 
However due to some reasons, ctrl +alt+tab is not opening the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply alt + tab to cycle through programs, shift + alt + tab goes backwards (left).

Comment: Alt-Tab will switch between apps Ctrl-Alt-Tab is supposed to open the app switching window and force it to stay open even if you release the keys so that you can select from the icons.

Comment: WinKey and Tab is nice too. (Aero must be enabled)

Comment: Yeah. Anything to be done for ctrl alt tab to work? For me it is not working? Alt tab and shift alt tab when a lot of windows open is very annoying

Comment: My sticky keys is disabled. Is that the reason why ctrl alt tab not working?

Comment: Sticky Keys is for extremely slow typers, it's almost an accessibility feature. You shouldn't need that to use ctrl-alt-tab.

My Ctrl-alt-tab doesn't work either.